# Go testing get caller line number

Tags: go, testing

Example code:

```golang
package main

import "testing"

func TestOne(t *testing.T) {
    assertEq(t, "A", "B")
    assertEq(t, "B", "B")
    assertEq(t, "C", "X")
}

func TestTwo(t *testing.T) {
    assertEq(t, "A", "A")
    assertEq(t, "B", "B")
    assertEq(t, "C", "D")
}

func assertEq(t *testing.T, a, b string) {
    if a != b {
        t.Fatalf("%s != %s, in %s", a, b, t.Name())
    }
}
```

Output:

```
=== RUN   TestOne
    prog.go:19: A != B, in TestOne
--- FAIL: TestOne (0.00s)
=== RUN   TestTwo
    prog.go:19: C != D, in TestTwo
--- FAIL: TestTwo (0.00s)
FAIL
```

If I call `assertEq()` many times, it is difficult to find what is line where the test failed. Can I get the caller line number?

Comment: "Can I get the caller line number?" Yes but that is overkill. Call t.Helper.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`runtime.Caller`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Caller).

```golang
package main

import (
    "testing"
    "runtime"
)

func TestOne(t *testing.T) {
    assertEq(t, "A", "B")
    assertEq(t, "B", "B")
    assertEq(t, "C", "X")
}

func TestTwo(t *testing.T) {
    assertEq(t, "A", "A")
    assertEq(t, "B", "B")
    assertEq(t, "C", "D")
}

func assertEq(t *testing.T, a, b string) {
    if a != b {
        _, f, l, _ := runtime.Caller(1)
        t.Fatalf("%s:%d %s != %s, in %s", f, l, a, b, t.Name())
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/EWoYhiGugDg